# hover and if statement firing only ONCE

Tags: javascript, jquery

mouseover should be bound as event that checks "if" statement each time mouse enters 
a region of `.input-medium`, but "if" checks only 1 time. Of there would be no class and "if"
becomes false - hover will still be working.

I need to check if class exists each time.

```
$('.input-medium').on('mouseover' , function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'error-highlight') {
           $(this).hover(
                  function() {
                      $('<p class="reg-tooltip">test test</p>').appendTo('body');
                  },

                  function() {
                      $('p').remove();
                  });
       }
});
```

Comment: small mistake - i mean id ofc and not a class

Comment: Don't create the hover handler inside the mouseover handler - that will create more and more hover handlers, one every time the mouseover handler is triggered. If that's the only thing you're doing in the mouseover handler you don't need it. Just say `$(.input-medium").hover(...);`

Comment: @nnnnnn well, it seems that there was more than one problem here ;) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: Add the `if` condition to `hover` itself:

```
$('.input-medium').hover(
     function() {
         if (this.id === 'error-highlight') {
             $('<p class="reg-tooltip">test test</p>').appendTo('body');
         }
     },
     function() {
         $('p.reg-tooltip').remove(); // <-- Always remove temporary element
     }
);
```